# No speech heard for conv.ask('...'') in actions.intent.PERMISSION

Tags: permissions, text-to-speech, actions-on-google, fulfillment

In my Actions sdk `MAIN` intent I ask the user permission to access their name. I use the *Actions on Google* simulator for testing.

When in the corresponding `actions.intent.PERMISSION` event I want to confirm this to the user, the text (first name) appears on the screen, but I do not hear it spoken.

In the *Audio* tab of the simulator, the speech text is visible too, but at the bottom it shows a zero duration. Why is that? Is there something special about the `PERMISSION` event? My code:

```
app.intent('actions.intent.PERMISSION', 
  (conv, input, granted) => 
  {
    let name = conv.user.name;

    if (granted) 
      conv.ask (`your first name is ${name.given}`); // shown on screen, but not heard !!
    else
      conv.ask (`your did not give permission`); // ...
    ...
})
```

Comment: You didn't tag any languages, frameworks, or platforms (where applicable). Please fix the tagging to include relevant information. The current tags don't really say much

Comment: I promise I will do that next time ... Yesterday, I got the following answer from Google Support: _Thank you for the update.
Yes, there is a known issue with TTS in the Simulator and our team is actively working on resolving it. I suggest you to use a mobile device or Google Home to test your App to get correct TTS_